# Change text box value where id equal to "some string"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this script

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" name="testing"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde3" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde4" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde5" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde6" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde7" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="ItmCde8" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Call_Desc" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="Desc" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc2" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc3" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc4" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc5" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc6" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc7" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc8" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want it works like this: When I change `ItmCod`,`Desc` change. When I change `ItmCod2`, `Desc2` change. When I change `ItmCod3`, `Desc3` change. And so on.

All I know is to change a text box, you have to do something like this

```
Desc.Text ="some value"
```

how could I change a value of a text box using a variable like this

```
somestringvariable+1.Text="some value"
somestringvariable+2.Text="some value"
```

I'm new to this programming language. Please explain more. Or give me some direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: This one compiles and runs.

```
protected void Call_Desc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch ((sender as TextBox).ID)
        {
            case "ItmCde":
                //actions
                Desc.Text = ItmCde.Text;
                break;
            case "ItmCde2":
                Desc2.Text = ItmCde2.Text;
                //actions
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

```
protected void Call_Desc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string mainTextBox = "ItmCde";
        string secondaryTextBox = "Desc";

        // Get a reference to the ContentPlaceHolder
        ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = this.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;

        int ix = 0, index = 0; 

        if ((sender as TextBox) != null)
        {
            ix = (sender as TextBox).ID.IndexOf(mainTextBox);

            if (ix != -1)
            {
                int.TryParse((sender as TextBox).ID.Substring(ix + mainTextBox.Length), out index);
                secondaryTextBox = index > 0 ? secondaryTextBox + index : secondaryTextBox;
                mainTextBox = index > 0 ? mainTextBox + index : mainTextBox;

                (MainContent.FindControl(secondaryTextBox) as TextBox).Text = (MainContent.FindControl(mainTextBox) as TextBox).Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will case a postback (a small flicker). Else you can also use Javascript JQuery to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: You are right. But what if I there are 20 text box. I have to repeat the "case"  20 times. The number of the text box is based on user input. Sorry if I didn't make the question clear enough for you.

Comment: @Samadung First judge if the sender string starts with "ItmCde" then get the following substring and convert to number, then use JQuery to select the correspondent "Desc", in the end change its value.

Answer (score 0):

You already subscribed on OnTextChanged with "Call_Desc" so it's simple like:

```
    public void Call_Desc(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              switch(((TextBox)sender).ID)
                {
                    case "ItmCde":
                       Desc.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
                       break;
                     case "ItmCde2":
                       Desc2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
                       break;
                      case ..
                }


        }
```

Sorry if there is any typo missing as i didn't test it on IDE but it should work

Comment: You are right. But what if I there are 20 text box. The number of the text box is based on user input. Sorry if I didn't make the question clear enough for you.

Comment: I don't understand your point, do you want it to generated dynamic? or you don't want to have too many cases. Let it more clearer in order for me to help u well

Comment: Both, the TextBox will be dynamic and I don't think using cases is a good answer. I think something like looping.

Comment: You didn't illustrate that in the question, please update your question